# How would I write "the first day t such that f(t)>0" in mathematical notation?

Tags: optimization, notation

Suppose there is some function $f(t)$, and we want to know the first day $t\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $f(t)>0$. How would I write this in mathematical notation? I would imagine that it involves argmin, such as $argmin_{t\in\{1,...,n\}}(*\textit{some function of the condition}*)$. However, I'm blanking on how to actually write that interior part. I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: $\min\{t \in \{1, \dots, n\} : f(t) > 0\}$.

Comment: @Mason that is it. Wow - it's been a long day I suppose. Thank you, Mason.